# How can I sort two SELECT query and combine them

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table like below which holds user records. I want to list the users whose permission field is 0 first and then the users with permission 1. But I also want to sort them alphabetically.

This is my table:

```
users
--------------------------------
user_id     name     permission
1           jack      0
2           anne      0
3           kate      0
4           steve     1
5           roger     0
6           judy      1
7           robin     0
8           stella    1
9           arthur    0
```

And I want to get the this result:

```
users
---------------------------------
user_id       name       permission
2             anne       0
9             arthur     0
1             jack       0
3             kate       0
7             robin      0
5             roger      0
6             judy       1
8             stella     1
4             steve      1
```

As you can see, there are two groups, first the users with permission "0" and later permission "1". But each group is also sorted alphabetically in itself.

```
(
SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
ORDER BY name ASC
)
UNION (

SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
ORDER BY name ASC
)
ORDER BY permission ASC
```

I've tried to get the two groups separately by sorting and combine them but it is not working in the way I want.

Comment: what result are you actually getting?

Comment: Are `users` and `name` two different tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A code like below works

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
ORDER BY permission ASC , username ASC
```

you should write the name of the column that you want to initially order by first, then the second, third, etc

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM users
ORDER BY 
        permission ASC, 
        name ASC;
```

You don't need two separate queries

First the result set is sorted in ascending order (from lower to higher) based on the value of `permission` column.

Now you have a sorted list where all the records having `0` as `permission` will appear first.

Next, if you apply another sort on `name` column on this sorted list then it will make an alphabetical sorted list where the previous sorting order holds as well as this one.

---

**Test:**

```
create table users(
  id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50),
  permission int
 );

INSERT INTO users(name,permission)
VALUES ('A',1),('D',0),('C',0),('B',1);

SELECT * FROM users;

id     name   permission

1        A       1
2        D       0
3        C       0
4        B       1
```

---

```
#Sort only by permission (ASC)

SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY permission ASC;

id     name   permission

2        D       0
3        C       0
1        A       1
4        B       1
```

---

```
#Sort first by permission (ASC), then by name (ASC)

SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY permission ASC, name ASC;

id     name   permission

3        C       0
2        D       0
1        A       1
4        B       1
```

---

[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bab1b0/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can just sort by both fields. No need to do whatsoever.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM yourtable 
ORDER BY name ASC, 
         permission ASC
```

Comment: It's a typo. It should be "order by".